# Combining two sprites in one sprite (Libgdx)

Tags: android, libgdx

I would like to combine two sprites into one.
For example:

```
private Sprite spriteGirl;
private Sprite spriteSweater;
private Sprite spriteDressed; 
..................................................................
atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/images.pack"));

spriteGirl = atlas.createSprite("girl");
spriteSweater = atlas.createSprite("sweater");
...................................................................
```

"spriteSweater" should be placed on the sprite "spriteGirl" (in certain coordinates). This combination is the sprite "spriteDressed".

After this, the resulting sprite "spriteDressed" could be animated.

I'd rather move "spriteDressed" instead of "spriteGirl" and "spriteSweater" separately.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a composite class that holds and manages the sprites it is composed of.

```
public class CompositeSprite {

    Array<Sprite> componentSprites;

    public CompositeSprite() {
        componentSprites = new Array<Sprite>();
    }

    public void addComponentSprite(Sprite sprite) {
        componentSprites.add(sprite);
    }

    // ... other methods left out for brevity

    public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
        for (Sprite sprite : componentSprites) {
            sprite.draw(batch)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, I was thinking of combining the sprites before drawing.

If we draw "spriteGirl" and this move (randomly) to a point (x,y), this position should be calculated continuously so that the "spriteSweater" can follow the steps of the "spriteGirl", keeping the relative position.

Instead, if we combine sprites before drawing (spriteDressed), It would not be necessary to estimate the position.

Comment: In that case, create a pixmap, draw both images to it then create a texture from that. Note this will not be very efficient but would fit your requirement. I would still recommend trying the composite approach as this will give better efficiency and greater flexibility.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll try both approaches.

Comment: Try use `FrameBuffer`. Draw in this buffer all, what you want and use it's texture to draw.